# Getting a schedule job unstuck in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a schedule job that calls a function every time. This function does a lot of thing that perhaps throw an exception or gives me an error.

This is done in a loop, so if an error occurs, the function stops working and gets stucked until I delete the entry that is causing the error (or fix the error).

Something like this:

```
public function process_documents()
{
$documents = document::where("processed", 0)->get();

foreach($documents as $document)
{
$this->do_this($document);
$this->do_that($document);
$this->finish($document);
}

}
```

Solutions that I have though:

1- Make a command that executes a command.

```
foreach($documents as $document)
{
Artisan::call("document:process",$document->id);
}
```

2- try catch everywhere

I know they both would work but I would like to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to find out why the process crashes and solve this problem.
You could write some code that handles the error, stores the problem in the database and skips the document until the problem is resolved.

Otherwise, I believe that your first solution will be the best way to separate the processing of the different documents. Your code will also be much cleaner.
Try-catches would only clog up your code.

Comment: Of course I fix it every time but I don't want to be babysitting production at 04:00 AM because something unexpected crashed. Especially when I am not the onyl one working in the project.

Comment: This is good advice. Although I think `try/catch` blocks have their purpose and place. @prgrm also mentions the function doing a lot. Look into separation of concerns, and break it up into smaller, more manageable functions.

Comment: I agree that one try/catch to find the problem per document would be ok. But as I understood it, he wanted to add a try catch over every single function.

Comment: Using multiple `try/catch` blocks in different places, to catch different exceptions and handle them differently isn't a bad thing, if done correctly and with consideration. But I do agree that just throwing them at a problem without due consideration would be wrong. Do you have a different view?

Answer (score 1):

The drawback of using commands inside commands is that you don't gain that much from it. You could actually just run the code inside the initial command and catch errors that way.

An alternative solution you can implement is running the code from inside the loop in a separate forked process, for instance by using [symfony/process](https://github.com/symfony/process) or [duncan3dc/fork-helper](https://github.com/duncan3dc/fork-helper).

Having implemented both of these with success for a use case similar to yours, it really depends on what your inner logic does. If the code can be ran simultaneously or not, forking the process allows you to keep your main process alive.

A small hint if you test this out, make sure to check db connections etc. These normally get lost during forking.